# Web API Restful Service C# Perform SQL Query

Tags: c#, rest

Working on a web api restful service.

I have a table called tests. The primary key is auto-increment. Each row contains a username and a test question. This DB is not really optimised, but it doesn't need to be.

Because the primary key is just an int to keep each row unique, there are many rows with duplicate usernames. This is fine.

I want to be able to return all rows with a matching username.

I want to be able to do it with a get request with the url: www.mywebsite.com/api/tests/{username}

The default controller methods in Visual Studio are only able to search by primary key to return one unique result.

This is something like what I want, but it doesn't work. 500 error. I'm not knowledgeable on debugging either, so point me in the right direction there if possible so I can provide more info.

```
    // GET: api/Tests/robert
    [ResponseType(typeof(Test))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetTest(string id)
    {
        //This is the default approach that just searches by primary key
        //Test test = await db.Tests.FindAsync(id);

        /*This is roughly what I want. Compiles, but doesn't work.*/

        var query = "SELECT* WHERE id=" + id;
        Test test =  db.Tests.SqlQuery(query, id);
        if (test == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(test);
    }
```

Let me know where I screwed up. I've been blundering over this for hours. I don't claim to be particularly good at any of this.

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring your method like this

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class HisController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Test(string name) {...}
}
```

Also, I would recommend You to use entity framework

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class HisController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Test(string name)
    {
        using (MyEntities bm = new MyEntities())
        {
            var usr = bm.Users.Where(u => u.Name == name ).ToList();

            if (usr.Count() > 0)
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new
                {
                    Success = true
                        ,
                    Message = "Total users: " + usr.Count()
                        ,
                    Data = usr
                });

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, new { Success = false, Message = "No users found..." });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would second the EF approach.  The code from the OP is open to a SQL injection attack.  You should never trust inputs and definitely not when you are sending them into a SQL query.

Comment: He'll never hit this method with www.mywebsite.com/api/tests/{username} unless he changes the default bindings.. the RouteConfig needs to be updated if he wants to use this URL schema for accessing this method.

Comment: Thats true, I assumed he had the right configuration for his class `[RoutePrefix("API")]
    public class HisController : ApiController
    {[HttpGet]
 public HttpResponseMessage Test(string name) {...}}`

Comment: I already use EF actually. Sorry for not saying already. I changed default bindings already also. The problem is explicitly about performing the query. I simply do not know how to write it.

Comment: Okay. Solved! It was just the line: var usr = bm.Users.Where(u => u.Name == name ).ToList();

That's all I needed. Thanks sdmon. I'm new to c# and some syntax looks scary to me.